# Can I have a microcontroller with one I²S module as digital signal processor?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, bluetooth, dac, digital-audio

I was not very sure what title I should use, but the idea is: We have a Bluetooth module (BM64) and a DAC (PCM5122.) We want to put the microcontroller (STM32 Nucleo-F303K8) in between  for digital signal processing. The problem is, the microcontroller only has one I²S module.

Can the DAC, Bluetooth module and microcontroller be on the same bus? In other words, can the STM32 act as a controller, select the BM64 for input, read the data, process it and then select the DAC for output and send out the data?

It is similar to SPI but in the datasheet of I²S I only saw the following picture where a controller is between, but there is no connection to the data line.

**EDIT: in the last paragraph i accidentally wrote I²C but i meant I²S, after days of doing research and seeing other people confuse them, i have myself made the very error i swore not to make**

[image: controller between BM and DAC]

Comment: If this has to happen in real time (streaming), the simple answer is no, this won't work.

Comment: @TypeIA do you have any idea as to how we then could go along with this. The only thing that comes up in my head is using another protocol or maybe just general I/O pins to immitate the I²S module? So it would be as if we had 2 I²S modules?

Comment: I don't see a path forward with this particular MCU. The bit rate and timing requirements are too tight for bit-banging. So you need two high-speed serial interfaces that can operate simultaneously. This part doesn't seem to offer that.

Answer (score -2):

It should work just fine using the I2C bus. You can even add other sensors if you like. Your schematic is incorrect, the SCL and SCL should go to all three parts, of course all the grounds are connected. I believe you can get all of the parts in the "Arduino format" where the parts are mounted on PCBs waiting for you to connect. That is a big plus as there should also be libraries for each of the devices, saving you a lot of time and effort. You probably can do the same with SPI, but there you will need three lines , SCK, MISO, and MOSI for each of the modules then you need to run a seperate CS\ Chip Select line to each of them.

Comment: I2S is a synchronous bus for digital audio. Not I2C.

Comment: EDIT: in the last paragraph i accidentally wrote I²C but i meant I²S, after days of doing research and seeing other people confuse them, i have myself made the very error i swore not to make